# Python как узнать имя компьютера?

Tags: python, python-3.x

можно-ли с помощью Python узанать имя компьютера?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Попробуйте [socket.gethostname](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.gethostname):

```
import socket
print(socket.gethostname())
```

Comment: [Или так.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1242481/337540)

Answer (score 2):

Я больше вот так люблю:

```
import platform
platform.node()
```

Comment: Хорошо выглядит :) Кст, под капотом оно вызывает `socket.gethostname()`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1erX.png