# как получить имя компьютера flask

Tags: python, веб-программирование, flask

При переходе на сайт я хочу узнать имя компьютера, если запрос идёт с него. Как это сделать? У меня была идея сделать через JS и дикие костыли.

Пример:
Пользователь заходит на сайт и на сервере нужно получить имя компьютера зашедшего пользователя

Это не дубликат вопроса [Python как узнать имя компьютера?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1237768/python-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Python как узнать имя компьютера?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1237768/python-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d1%8c%d1%8e%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0)

Comment: @Jack_oS Не-а, там речь о хосте, тут о клиенте XD

Comment: *сделать через JS и дикие костыли* - только так и можно. Стандартные HTTP запросы не содержат в себе информацию об имени хоста.